# Bizspark program and Azure

Tags: azure

From the link below, it seems like bizspark subscribers can use azure for dev/testing and production use. So the $150 monthly recurring credit is usable for both dev/test and production. I am unclear as to if the 120 hour limit applies to bizspark subscribers. There is a mention of the limit to msdn subscribers.

"
If you're with the bizspark program, the benefits page makes no mention of the "no production" or 120 hour detection thing that the regular benefits page does. However, there is still no SLA.
 "

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/06/03/windows-azure-announcing-major-improvements-for-dev-test-in-the-cloud.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BizSpark members retain production rights completely. This is detailed in the offer here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0064p/. It sounds confusing, but the associated BizSpark MSDN account does not have the dev/test restriction.

Key phrase:

> In addition, BizSpark members retain production use rights under this Azure benefits offer.

I have a BizSpark startup LLC that I've been using for over 1.5 years just fine on this program including long-running production IaaS VMs.

Comment: I was basing some of my comments based on this: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/msdn-benefits-b/ Another search shows *more* info about using credits for preoduction than *not*... but the information needs to be made more consistent.

Comment: Hi jeff, "It sounds confusing, but the associated BizSpark MSDN account does not have the dev/test restriction." This is the answer I was looking for! so this means, BizSpark MSDN account does not have the 120 hour restriction for development/testing.

Comment: Correct. I've shared this feedback with the teams.

Comment: I came across the same information as @JeffWilcox but there is a contradiction further down the same page:- "Use Rights - This benefit is for development and testing only. We reserve the right to suspend any instance (VM or cloud service) that runs continuously for more than 120 hours or if we determine that the instance is being used for production. Production workloads must be run on regular subscriptions." I have logged the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217534-documentation/suggestions/10858905-clarify-the-information-on-monthly-azure-credit-fo)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using BizSpark account for production purposes for our company. We get $150.00 credit per month towards Azure resources consumption. Currently because of some reasons we have enabled spending cap but you can very well remove spending cap and you get charged for whatever you have spent over this $150.00. So if your monthly consumption comes out to be $200.00 for example, you get charged $50.00. As a part of being a BizSpark member you get MSDN subscription as well though I am not sure that you can get 120 hours separately for MSDN subscription than your BizSpark credits.

Comment: I've heard that BizSpark $150 gets expired always until the end of the month even if you are not using it.